How to Resolve Error 404 "No virtual resource found" with the LinkedIn MemberSnapshot API?
I am working with the LinkedIn MemberSnapshot API and trying to retrieve data using Python with the requests library. However, I encounter a 404 error with the message "No virtual resource found" every time I attempt to send a GET request to the following endpoint:
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/memberSnapshotData?q=criteria 
Here is the code I am using to make the request:
access_token = ACCESS_TOKEN

headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'LinkedIn-Version': '202312'
}

url = "https://api.linkedin.com/rest/memberSnapshotData"

params = {
    'q': 'CONNECTIONS',
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)

The errors suggest that either the URL or the parameters of my request are incorrect. I have checked and double-checked the API documentation but cannot find what might be misconfigured.
Here's what I'd like to know:
Is the URL mentioned correct for accessing the LinkedIn MemberSnapshot API?
Is the parameter q='criteria' correctly used here? If not, what values are expected for this parameter?
Are there any additional headers or parameters that I should include in my requests?
Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

The problem lies in the fact that you have to let q=criteria in the url and set 'domain'='CONNECTIONS' in the params.
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'LinkedIn-Version': '202312'
    }

url = "https://api.linkedin.com/rest/memberSnapshotData?q=criteria"

params = {
    'domain':'CONNECTIONS',
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)


You need to set the value from the Products page, and then from the "Member Data Portability API (Member)" click on the "ViewEndpoints" link on that page you should see the list, and then you should compare it with the Request Methods documentation.
Then your code should look something like this (criteria for this endpoint):
access_token = ACCESS_TOKEN

url = "https://api.linkedin.com/rest/memberSnapshotData"
query_params = {
    "q": "criteria",
}

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "LinkedIn-Version": "202312"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=query_params)

